# Correct way to write a menu in standard C

Tags: c

I would like to write a menu like:

```
1. Foo
2. Bar
0. Quit

>
```

This menu should work in both piped or terminal mode:

```
$ ./menu
1. Foo
2. Bar
0. Quit

>1 oops no ! I wanted to do 2

Error: try again
>
```

And the piped mode:

```
$ printf 1 42 | ./menu
You chose Foo and entered 42
```

So I am looking for a way to empty the buffer when someone enter things like `1 something`. Otherwise I will go to the option `foo` and submit `something` to `scanf`.

Is there a way to empty the current buffer? To play around I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    bool is_tty = isatty(fileno(stdin));
    char c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            printf("Ignoring 0x%02hhx\n", c);
            continue; // Ignore spaces
        } else
        {
            printf("Got 0x%02hhx\n", c);
        }

        // Here I want to consume all the buffer...

        switch(c) {
            case 'q':
            {
                char d;
                if(scanf("%hhd", &d)) {
                    printf("Scanf got %hhd\n", d);
                } else {
                    printf("Scanf failed");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '0':
                printf("Exit with zero\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("Exit with EOF\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the rest of the current line and skip to the next line with this in `scanf`:

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

What this does:

- `%*[^\n]` discards all characters up to a newline
- `%*1[\n]` discards a newline if one is found
- Therefore, it reads all characters up to a newline, discards them, reads the newline, and discards it.

If you need to detect `EOF`, simply check if the return value of `scanf` is equal to `EOF`.